# convert a string to list of list

Tags: python

I get this string for example:

```py
s = '[1,0],[3,5],[5,6]'
```

I want to convert it to list.

If I do:

```py
s.split("[*,*]")
```

then it doesn't work

I want to get this:

```
[[1,0],[3,5],[5,6]]
```

Comment: @RVA92 this clearly won't work, it would also split the inner lists and keep the `[` and `]` characters.

Comment: Or better `ast.literal_eval`

Answer (score 2):

You might use `literal_eval` from `ast` module (part of standard library) for this task as follows

```
import ast
s = '[1,0],[3,5],[5,6]'
lst = list(ast.literal_eval(s))
print(lst)
```

output

```
[[1, 0], [3, 5], [5, 6]]
```

Note that `s` is literal for python's `tuple` so I used `list` for conversion into desired structure.

Answer (score 2):

If the input format is really fixed :

```py
out = [list(map(int, w.split(","))) for w in s[1:-1].split("],[")]
```

this may be faster but this may be less robust depending on input strict format than a real parsing solution like `literal_eval`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('[1,0],[3,5],[5,6]')
([1, 0], [3, 5], [5, 6])
```

`literal_eval` is more secure than `eval` in that it contains some logic to only actually evaluate valid literals.

Converting the result to a `list()` left as an exercise. (Hint hint.)